# How to Ignore Longer words when using Regex.split?

Tags: c#, regex, text

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"\b(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)\b", RegexOptions.None);
```

AND i have this text

```
BODY
bodyattrib
mybody
GR-BODY
attrib
123
```

and i would like the output to be like this

```
tmp[0] = "BODY"
tmp[1] = "bodyattrib\mybody\nGR-BODY\nattrib\n123"
```

so far no good
the output is always 3 array splitted with GR-BODY

Comment: You will need to post more code. Its quite confusing at the moment.

Comment: problem is that at `GR-BODY` there is a word boundry, too. Why do you use `split`, when you want your output to include the split separator?

Answer (score 0):

Use `^`special character:

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"\b(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|^BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)\b", RegexOptions.None);
```

`^` means `beginning of string or line`.

and if you like apply this to all words, use `^` for any words you like:

```
\b(^3DFACE|^3DSOLID|^ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|^ARC|^ATTDEF|^ATTRIB|^BODY|^CIRCLE|^DIMENSION|^ELLIPSE|^HATCH|^HELIX|^IMAGE|^INSERT|^LEADER|^LIGHT|^LWPOLYLINE|^MLINE|^MLEADERSTYLE|^MLEADER|^MTEXT|^OLEFRAME|^OLE2FRAME|^POINT|^POLYLINE|^RAY|^REGION|^SEQEND|^SHAPE|^SOLID|^SPLINE|^SUN|^SURFACE|^TABLE|^TEXT|^TOLERANCE|^TRACE|^UNDERLAY|^VERTEX|^VIEWPORT|^WIPEOUT|^XLINE|^LINE)\b
```

Other useful special character is `$` means `end of string or line`. you can enclose your words be these to ensure these words comes up in a line.

note that `^` and `$` depends on `Multiline` option.